# Called api not read object

Tags: reactjs, api, react-redux

When I call detail with console.log nothing show error **exam: console.log(coin.description.en);** But when I write this code **{coin.description.en}** in render not working and show this error:
**TypeError: can't access property "en", coin.description is undefined**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';

function CoinDetail({...props}) {
    const [coin,setCoin] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getCoinDetail(API_URL+'ripple');
    },[]);

    const getCoinDetail = (id) => {
        axios.get(id).then(res => {
            setCoin(res.data);
            console.log(res.data);
        });
    }
    
    return (
        <>
            Id: {coin.id}<br/>
            Name: {coin.name}<br/>
            Symbol: {coin.symbol}<br/>
            Description: {coin.description.en}<br/>
        </>
    );
}

function mapStateToProps(state,ownProps) {
    const coinId = ownProps.match.params.coinId;
    return {
        coinId
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CoinDetail);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `{coin.description && coin.description.en}` in place of just `{coin.description.en}`

Comment: thank you so much, but why use two time coin.description ?

Comment: `coin.description.en ` will be returned only when `coin.description ` is not undefined or null. Hence we are using `&&` for that.

Comment: and I want to get coinId from url, I tested but not working when I wrote alert work correct give id but when I use with url+coinId not work so why ?

const coinTest = props.coinId;
alert(coinTest);

Comment: @NikolayAndrv Can you please share your code in codesandbox